# Extensible tactic in Coq

Tags: coq, ltac

Let’s say I have a fancy tactic that solves lemmas of a certain kind:

```
Ltac solveFancy :=
  some_preparation;
  repeat (first [important_step1 | important_step2];
          some_cleanup);
  solve_basecase.
```

Now I use this tactic to prove further lemmas of that kind, which I subsequently want to use in this tactic.

```
Lemma fancy3 := …. Proof. … Qed.
Ltac important_step3 := apply fancy3;[some|specific|stuff].
```

Now I could simply re-define `Ltac solveFancy ::= …` and add `important_step3` to the list, but that quickly gets old.

Is there a more elegant way of now extending the list of `important_step`-tactics in `solveFancy`? I am imagining something like:

```
Add Hint SolveFancy important_step3.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an argument to `solveFancy` which you can use to pass in another tactic:

```
Ltac solveFancy hook :=
  some_preparation;
  repeat (first [important_step1 | important_step2 | hook];
          some_cleanup);
  solve_basecase.

(* use solveFancy without any extra available steps *)
[...] solveFancy fail [...]

Ltac important_step3 := [...]

(* use solveFancy with important_step3 *)
[...] solveFancy important_step3 [...]
```

This is somewhat more elegant than redefining a hook, though it doesn't solve the extensibility problem by itself.  The following is a strategy for repeatedly redefining a tactic `x` in terms of previous versions of itself, using the fact that modules allow redefining an Ltac name without overwriting the previous definition.

```
Ltac x := idtac "a".

Goal False.
  x. (* a *)
Abort.

Module K0.
  Ltac x' := x.
  Ltac x := x'; idtac "b".
End K0.
Import K0.

Goal False.
  x. (* a b *)
Abort.

Module K1.
  Ltac x' := x.
  Ltac x := x'; idtac "c".
End K1.
Import K1.

Goal False.
  x. (* a b c *)
Abort.
```

Note that the names `K0`, `K1` of the modules don't matter and they can be renamed or reordered however you want.  This isn't the most elegant thing in the world but I think it's an improvement.

Comment: I like the module-based approach!

Answer (score 1):

It's not what I'd call elegant, but here's a pure Ltac solution. You can leave a hook in your tactic which you re-define later, and you can keep following this pattern by always leaving a hook for the next hint:

```
Axiom P : nat -> Prop.
Axiom P0 : P 0.
Axiom P_ind : forall n, P n -> P (S n).

Ltac P_hook := fail.

Ltac solve_P :=
  try apply P_ind;
  exact P0 || P_hook.

Theorem ex_1 : P 1.
Proof.
  solve_P.
Qed.

Ltac P_hook2 := fail.
Ltac P_hook ::= exact ex_1 || P_hook2.

Theorem ex_2 : P 2.
Proof.
  solve_P.
Qed.

Ltac P_hook3 := fail.
Ltac P_hook ::= exact ex_2 || P_hook3.

Theorem ex_3 : P 3.
Proof.
  solve_P.
Qed.
```

There should be a way to do this with `Hint Extern`, but it'll be much harder to control when and in what order those hints are tried, and they have to fully solve the goal by the end.

Comment: Yes, something along these lines is the best I can think of as well. It is it is annoyting to keep the numbers in sync, though; if you add a lemma in the middle of your file, you have to renumber everything.